# bi-directional motor using SPDT relay and diodes

Tags: motor, relay, dc, spdt

I have a bi-directional motor that I am trying to control using an SPDT relay. It is only working in one direction when I remove the circuit for the opposite direction, and it is either shorting or just not starting no matter what I try. Below is my circuit. Any ideas on how to improve this so it works?

EDIT: I realize the diodes are drawn backwards here, but I did put them in the correct direction

[image]

Comment: This can't possibly work because (with the diodes the other way around) the battery is basically shorted out on the bottom side of the motor

Comment: The only way something like it could possibly work is if you get the other side of the motor to stay at half the battery voltage, which requires you to build a circuit that's harder than using a DPDT relay

Comment: wouldn't the diodes prevent the current from flowing backwards to the battery?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a DPDT relay; I do have access to resistors, transistors, resistors, diodes etc; is this something that can be done with a SPDT relay and other components?

Comment: It's certainly possible with transistors and resistors since you can make something that behaves like a relay on the bottom side of the motor

Comment: If you have transistors, build an "H bridge" from 4 of them.

Comment: the motor is not in the battery circuit ... it is bypassed by a short circuit through the switch

Comment: could it potentially work if I hook up to L298N motor controller? I have a lot of them

Comment: You couild use two SPDT relays with their coills connected in parallel, so they would "look like" a DPDT relay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't possibly work. The battery is basically shorted out on the bottom side of the motor.

The only way something like it could possibly work is if you get the other side of the motor to stay at half the battery voltage, without shorting it out. That's possible, but you'll only get half the motor's speed, and you'd have to either waste tons of power (wasting the battery really quickly) with a voltage divider, or make a more complicated circuit that's more complicated than getting a DPDT relay.

---

(noting that the diodes are actually the opposite way to how they're drawn in the picture) The diodes do not prevent current from flowing backwards to the battery. I don't understand what you mean by that. The diodes allow the current to flow in the same direction that it wants to flow anyway - i.e. from one side of the battery to the other - so they don't make any meaningful difference. If you turn either diode around it will block all the current and nothing at all will happen.

Comment: Ok.. how come it only blocks the current in one direction but not the other?

Comment: @SamanthaCruz That's literally the point of a diode

Comment: ok, but how come when I turn the diode it doesn't prevent the current in the other direction, to clarify

Comment: @SamanthaCruz It does. But that's no use because now it blocks all the current coming from the battery.

Comment: @SamanthaCruz You are aware that current flows in loops, right? it doesn't come from the battery and go to the motor, rather it comes from the + side, goes through the circuit and goes to the - side. And if it can't go the whole way around, it won't go anywhere at all

Comment: yes, I understand that it keeps the current flowing to the battery in the correct direction. I thought this would prevent a short. It actually works for LEDs, so I am guessing the motor is what is causing it to short?

Comment: @SamanthaCruz It shouldn't work for LEDs, either. But I don't know what circuit you made with the LEDs. Maybe it was a different circuit that did work.

Comment: @SamanthaCruz The short is what's causing it to short. See how the current comes out of the + side, through a diode, through a wire, through another diode, then into the - side? That is the short circuit. (Most short circuits are just a wire, but your one has two diodes in it)

Comment: multisim simulation https://docs.google.com/document/d/1T6yArCEpagoap7SdsgnPIOYxFpBsPiMZNzjSUh3VCWY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ahh ok I see what you're saying now

Comment: couldn't adding diodes in opposite directions on the bottom connected to the motor work? This would prevent the short when it's going the wrong direction

Comment: @SamanthaCruz You couldn't make it work in both directions without making it a short circuit

Comment: ok I don't know why I didn't see that before; thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it: -

[image]

It requires two change-over relay contacts operating in tandem. You might also wish to apply back-emf quenching diodes too. Here's another version of the same circuit (from [here](https://forum.digikey.com/t/polarity-reversal-using-a-dpdt-switch/626))showing how the 12 volts get routed to one side and then the other: -

[image]

Image from [how to control DC motor direction using relay](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/how-to-control-dc-motor-direction-using-relay/299927).

The relay contacts form, what is known as, a H-bridge and, a H bridge can also be made from transistors if you ever decided that might work better for you.